# Unit Test Angular ----> Error: Cannot make XHRs from within a fake async test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm having trouble creating the unit test for my "homepage" component.
I want to test the function loadNews().
This is the error: Error: Cannot make XHRs from within a fake async test. Request URL: https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/4657586786.json

I write below the code:

HOMEPAGE.COMPONENT.TS

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServiceService } from '../service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.css'],
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {
  allNewsId: Array<number>;
  newsId: Array<number>;
  news: Array<any> = [];
  i = 0;

  constructor(private service: ServiceService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getAllNews().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.allNewsId = data;
      this.loadNews();
    });
  }

  loadNews() {
    this.newsId = this.allNewsId.slice(0, this.i + 10);
    while (this.i < this.newsId.length) {
      this.service.getOneNews(this.newsId[this.i]).subscribe((el) => {
        this.news.push(el);
      });
      this.i++;
    }
  }

  addNews() {
    this.loadNews();
  }
}
```

SERVICE.SERVICE.TS

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ServiceService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAllNews() {
    return this.http.get(
      'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/newstories.json'
    );
  }

  getOneNews(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(
      `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${String(id)}.json`
    );
  }
}
```

HOMEPAGE.COMPONENT.SPEC.TS

```
import {
  ComponentFixture,
  fakeAsync,
  flush,
  TestBed,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ServiceService } from '../service.service';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('HomepageComponent', () => {
  let component: HomepageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomepageComponent>;
  let service: ServiceService;
  let httpClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HomepageComponent],
      imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
      providers: [ServiceService],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomepageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get']);
    service = new ServiceService(httpClientSpy as any);

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('loadNews()', fakeAsync(() => {
    const newsSample = {
      by: '',
      descendants: 0,
      id: 768678,
      score: 1,
      time: 123454345654,
      title: '',
      type: '',
      url: '',
    };
    component.allNewsId = [67854, 67546, 456789654, 63457687985746, 4657586786];
    spyOn(service, 'getOneNews').and.returnValue(of(newsSample));
    component.loadNews();
    flush();
    expect(component.loadNews).toHaveBeenCalled;
  }));
});
```

can you help me please??
Thank You!

Comment: well, we'd need a lot more information like the code that  you are tring to test (the code, not an image), and what have you tried? What is the problem with the test that you did write? Can we see it?

Comment: you are absolutely right. I wrote the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the HttpCientTestingModule

Official documentation at https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Comment: thanks, the error has been resolved... now mark me "SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS loadNews()".        Can you help me please??

Comment: If you have another question, please ask another question.